# How can I create a virtual env for different version of python?

Tags: python, virtualenv

when I run this:

```
python3 -m venv myproj
```

It will create a python 3.6 environment and I need to create a 3.5. I have both versions installed, how can I chose?

Thanks
Miguel

Comment: `python3.5 -m venv myproj`?

Comment: python 3.5 is not recognized as a command